# Wait for animation in other function to finish

Tags: jquery, function, events, animation, wait

The key words are "in other function"

Here is what I mean:

```
function MyFunction()
{
     $("#bob").animate({left: 300}, 1000);
}


$('a').click(function(ev){
     ev.preventDefault();
     MyFunction();

     //How can the line below execute after the animation in MyFunction is done?
     document.location = $(this).attr('href')
}
```

Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function MyFunction(url)
{
     $("#bob").animate({left: 300}, 1000, function() {
         // this callback function will execute
         // after animation complete
         // so you can do the location change here
         document.location = url;
     });
}


$('a').click(function(ev){
     ev.preventDefault();
     MyFunction($(this).attr('href')); // passing the url to MyFunction()
});
```

Its good to use `on()`

```
$('a').on('click', function(ev){
     ev.preventDefault();
     MyFunction($(this).attr('href')); // passing the url to MyFunction()
});
```

Comment: yeah but it says I have to wait another 5 minutes

Answer (score 3):

Two routes for this one.

The callback route:

```
function MyFunction(callback) {
     $("#bob").animate({left: 300}, 1000, callback);
}

$('a').click(function(ev){
     ev.preventDefault();
     MyFunction(function() { document.location = $(this).attr('href') });
}
```

And the deferred route:

```
function MyFunction() {
     var def = new $.Deferred();
     $("#bob").animate({left: 300}, 1000, function() { def.resolve() });
     return def.promise();
}

$('a').click(function(ev){
     ev.preventDefault();
     MyFunction()
     .done(function() { document.location = $(this).attr('href') });
}
```